# Django - Can I create a Serializer without connecting to a model?

Tags: python, django

From the book, I do this to create a `Serializers`

```
class Serielizer_RecalculateDeliveryPromise(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    service_type = serializers.CharField(max_length = 10, write_only= True, required= True )
    package_type = serializers.CharField(max_length = 68, write_only= True,  required= True )
    origin_handover_point = serializers.CharField(max_length = 68, write_only= True, required= True  )
    destination_handover_point = serializers.CharField(max_length = 68, write_only= True,required= True  )
    class Meta:
        model = Input_RecalculateDeliveryPromise
        fields = ['service_type', 'package_type', 'origin_handover_point', 'destination_handover_point']


class Input_RecalculateDeliveryPromise(models.Model):
    service_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10, db_index = True)
    package_type = models.CharField(max_length = 68, db_index = True)
    origin_handover_point = models.CharField(max_length = 68, db_index = True)
    destination_handover_point = models.CharField(max_length = 68, db_index = True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['service_type', 'package_type', 'origin_hp','destination_hp']
```

My personal purpose of `Serializer` is simply to check the input only.

Therefore, I wonder if there is anyway that I could create a Serializer only without connecting to any model since it lengthen my code a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use serializers.Serializer instead of serializers.ModelSerializer

```
class Serielizer_RecalculateDeliveryPromise(serializers.Serializer):
    service_type = serializers.CharField(max_length = 10, write_only= True, required= True )
    package_type = serializers.CharField(max_length = 68, write_only= True,  required= True )
    origin_handover_point = serializers.CharField(max_length = 68, write_only= True, required= True  )
    destination_handover_point = serializers.CharField(max_length = 68, write_only= True,required= True  )
```